# Using wildcard in unix find command's path

Tags: ssh, unix, find, wildcards, ksh

This command with a * in the find path works fine on the local server

```
Svr1$ find /path/*/foo/ -name "*20160208"
```

When I try this remotely from another server it doesn't work

```
Svr2$ echo $Pswd|ssh Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo -S find /path/*/foo/ -name "*20160208*"
```

The error message is:

```
find: stat() error /path/*/foo/: No such file or directory
```

However, if I change the search path to avoid using the * it works fine. 
Like this:

```
Svr2$ echo $Pswd|ssh Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo -S find /path/ -name "*20160208*"
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I need to quote or escape part of the string but I just cannot figure it out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `*` is expanded by your local shell. You should quote your argument

```
ssh Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo -S find '/path/*/foo/' -name "20160208"
```

Comment: Precisely. The * never arrives at the remote computer. It has been expanded before you reach that stage.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matteo said, you need to escape the `*` from your local shell.  He's done that in his first example:

```
ssh Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo -S find '/path/*/foo/' -name "20160208"
```

As alternative, either of these should work as well, as the single quotes (`'...'`) and backslash (`\`) "hide" the `*` wildcard from your local shell:

```
ssh -t Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo 'find /path/*/foo/ -name *20160208'
```

or

```
ssh -t Svr1 /usr/local/bin/sudo find /path/\*/foo/ -name \*20160208
```

As a side note, see that I've included a `-t` argument to `ssh` so that `sudo` has a tty through which to ask for my password, which is *MUCH* better than putting the password on the command line, IMO.  If you must pipe the `sudo` password in, I suggest doing it via `cat secret.txt | find ...`, which keeps the password out of the command line which is potentially visible to `ps` and to anyone with access to your shell history (including `~/.history` and variants)