# Where is the bin directory of OpenSSL located in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to provide `/path/to/openssl/bin` to a build command, but I can't for the life of me find the OpenSSL installation in Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried this:

```
$ sudo find / -name openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

...but that doesn't find the `bin` dir. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the command does not simply need the full path-to-openssl-binary, which is /usr/bin/openssl on your system?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a build directory. In my build, it couldn't find `libssl.a` or `libcrypto.a` but these libraries were located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, in Ubuntu 16.04. I think you need to modify some of the gcc commands in that makefile to use that library location.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got the exact same error message, but after running `./configure --help` I realized that there's no flag for inputting the install directory of OpenSSL.

After some more research, I came across this [Server Fault post](https://serverfault.com/q/249340) and installed the OpenSSL development package using `sudo apt install libssl-dev` and then reran my `./configure` file and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for exact name "openssl". It does not find if the directory is let's say: "usr/lib/openssl_1_0/". I don't know how the regular expressions work with this command but try sudo find / -name openssl* maybe?

Comment: But be sure to quote wildcards so they are not expanded before being passed to the command (see [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/1037614/using-wildcard-in-unix-find-commands-path)): `sudo find / -name "openssl*"`